# Batch-Run FOR loop through cases.

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have cases that set variables.  The case is selected based on the users input.  When the case is executed, the variables are sent to a :RUN label where they are pushed through some code.

What I want to do: When the user enters "ALL" for an input is to have a loop that goes through every case and processes those variables through the :RUN label. I am not sure if you can design a FOR loop to go through all the cases or not.  I am completely open to suggestions.

Thanks

```
    SET /P PROCESS="Choose a process to run: "
```

`2>NUL CALL :%PROCESS% # jump to :CASES.
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :ALL # if label doesn't exist
ECHO Done.
EXIT /B

:PROCESS1
set runProcess1A=Yes
set runProcess1B=No
set runProcess1C=Yes
goto RUN

:PROCESS2
set runProcess2A=Yes
set runProcess2B=Yes
set runProcess2C=Yes
goto RUN

:PROCESS3
set runProcess3A=Yes
set runProcess3B=No
set runProcess3C=No
goto RUN

:ALL

REM CODE NEEDED HERE TO RUN THROUGH ALL THE CASES (PROCESS1 PROCESS2 AND PROCESS3).

:RUN
rem If process1A==Yes, then do something ETC`

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
REM Assumes the input will be a number between 1 and 3, or the word ALL
SET /P PROCESS="Choose a process to run: "

SET P1=Yes No Yes
SET P2=Yes Yes Yes
SET P3=Yes No No

IF "%PROCESS%"=="ALL" (
    FOR %%Z IN (1 2 3) DO FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3" %%A IN (!P%PROCESS%!) DO (
        SET runProcess%Z%A=%%A
        SET runProcess%Z%B=%%B
        SET runProcess%Z%C=%%C
) ELSE (
    FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3" %%A IN (!P%PROCESS%!) DO (
        SET runProcess%PROCESS%A=%%A
        SET runProcess%PROCESS%B=%%B
        SET runProcess%PROCESS%C=%%C
    )
)

:RUN
...
```